# Filepicker.io - Transfer file to server without downloading to device

Tags: ios, filepicker.io

Is it possible to configure filepicker.io so that when a remote file is picked, it will be transferred directly to their server (or to an external container), but NOT download it to the device?

I tried:

```
[fpController setShouldDownload:NO];
[fpController setShouldUpload:YES];
```

but this results in `FPPickerControllerDidCancel` to be called when a remote file is selected.

Comment: I'm curious if you ever figured this out.

Comment: Nope. Moved on to other problems. Not ideal.